# How to "catch" a handled exception in a class from the script using the the class?

Tags: php

I have a script that looks like this:

```
require ("class-pdowrapper.php");
$db = new DB();

$baddata = 'abc'; //should be an integer!!

$db->bind("myinteger", $baddata);
$sql = "INSERT INTO t_numbers (theinteger) VALUES (:myinteger)";
$result = $db->query($sql);

if ($result == 1) {
    echo "success.";
} else {
    echo "didn't work..."; //question relates to this line
}
```

If `$baddata` is "abc" i.e. a string, the class will handle the exception and output something like this:

> Unhandled Exception. 
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'abc' for column 'theinteger' at row 1
>   You can find the error back in the log

The class does this by something like:

```
private function query($statement) {
    try {
        // stuff
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $this->ExceptionLog($e->getMessage(), $query);
        die();
    } 
}



private function ExceptionLog($message, $sql = "") {
        $exception = 'Unhandled Exception. <br />';
        $exception .= $message;
        $exception .= "<br /> You can find the error back in the log.";

        if (!empty($sql)) {
            $message .= "\r\nRaw SQL : " . $sql;
        }
        return $exception;
}
```

So the question is, how can a script acknowledge the exception thrown and handled in the class and use the knowledge to do something. In my case, I could show the user an error or email the administrator to show that something isn't working with the database-related code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you catch the exception, then it is stopped from travelling up the stack, so you do not have the opportunity to »re-catch« it.

Basically you can either »re-throw« an Exception of a custom type, by creating a custom Error type like so:

```
class DataInsertException extends Exception {}
```

and than later:

```
try {
    // stuff
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $this->ExceptionLog($e->getMessage(), $query);
    throw new DataInsertException();
}
```

That way you can »filter« exceptions within the try catch statement:

```
try {} catch (DataInsertException $error) {}
```

whenever you deal with the database. All other Errors wont be caught by that block.

Or you can also add a `$errors` property to your `DB` class.

```
class DB {
  private $errors;

  public function __construct(){
    $this->errors = [];
  }

  public function insert(){
    try {}
    catch($error) {
      array_push($this->errors, $error);
    }
  }

  public function getErrors() {
    return $this->errors;
  }
}
```

That way, you can check the `$db` Object after each Transaction if it has Errors and react on that.

I would prefer a custom Error

Answer (score 0):

You need validate all your variables before you send it to server 
it is right way because you don't send incorrect request to server side.

like this (it is only sample)

```
<?php

class sampleClass 
{

    public function __construct($data) {

        if ($this->validateData($data)) {
            //do something
            $this->runRequest($data);
        } else {
            //parse errors
            //var_dump($data);
        }
    }

    private function validateData($data) {

        foreach($data as $currentData) {

            if ($currentData['type'] == 'integer' && is_int($currentData['value'])) {
                return false;
            }

            if ($currentData['type'] == 'string' && is_string($currentData['value'])) {
                return false;
            }

        }

        return true;
    }

    private function runRequest($data) {
    }

}

$data = [
    'correct_age' => [
        'type' => 'integer',
        'value'  => 88
        ],
    'incorrect_age' => [
        'type'  => 'integer',
        'value'  => 'abc'
        ],
    'incorrect_name' => [
        'type' => 'string',
        'value' => 111
        ]
    ];

$test = new sampleClass($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many options here. Here're some of them:

1. You can rethrow an Exception in you `catch (PDOException $e) {` block and make another `try ... catch ...` in your script. So you would handle logging in your `query` method and then handle application-related logic in the script file itself:

   ```
   try {  
      $result = $db->query($sql);
   } catch (AnotherException $e) {
      ...
   }
   ```
2. You can return complex result from `query()`, like this (it's only a draft):

   ```
   $result = array(
       'status' => true|false (or 'error' => true|false),
       'data'   => ... (valid data on success, error details data on error)
   )
   ```

   And then you can handle this result with no problems.